# How Can I install Symfony with the version by composer?

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I'd like to install a special version of Symfony by Composer? I've looked over the documentation and it recommends to use Symfony package but I want to install it by composer. Is there any way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can find the command here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/setup.html#creating-symfony-applications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, as I understood, you are able to run this command to install Symfony by the composer. In this command, you're going to install Symfony in a particular version.

`composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton example-project "4.2.*"`

Comment: Please be careful though which version constraint to use. Symfony 4.2 is not maintained anymore and doesn't receive bugfixes any longer.